# HTML 5 Manifest has different behavior across multiple browsers

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, firefox, manifest

I added some settings on my HTML 5 Manifest which resulted perfect behavior on Google Chrome and

Safari on iOS and Safari as a web clip on iOS.

Unfortunately the same code results in abort on loading manifest files in IE and Fire Fox.

Here is the settings we applied:

In server side: IIS 7, Windows Server 2008 R2.
Response: text/cache-manifest , no-cache.

And the text of manifest is :

```
CACHE MANIFEST


CACHE:

/
/Index.html
/Login.html
/favicon.ico
/Content/Kendo/web/Font/FontAwesome.otf

NETWORK:
*
```

And here is the result of IE Network profiler for the first file

```
URL: http://192.168.0.220:1009/

Method:

Result: (Aborted)

Type: text/html

Received: 292 B

Taken: < 1 ms

Initiator: (Pending...)
```

And here is the response:

```
Key Value

Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store

Pragma  no-cache

Content-Type    text/html

Expires -1

Last-Modified   Mon, 23 Sep 2013 16:05:06 GMT

Accept-Ranges   bytes

ETag    "351169ab76b8ce1:0"

Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5

X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

Date    Mon, 23 Sep 2013 16:32:43 GMT
```

And this is a error message of html 5 manifest:

```
Resource doesn’t exist on the server: 'http://192.168.0.220:1009/'. 
AppCache Fatal Error
```

And finally I've these meta tags on Index.html page:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
<meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a reason for the problem.

In Request_End in ASP.NET Global.asax we should apply

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

only for iOS, and chrome is always working, both for updating application and for offline usage.

Note: *no-store* is needed in web clip and safari of iOS, because of files which are already loaded before updating manifest, else they won't be updated, even when manifest downloads new version of them.

Hope this helps you too.